# Favourite Tags don't animate

Tags: bug, status-reproduced, design, tags

The tags on the Favourite Tags list don't animate in the same way that normal tags do:

[image]

For comparison — normal tags:

[image]

Comment: Repro on Safari 7.0.2 and Chrome 32.0.1700.77

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) as tags are not animated anywhere any more, to my moderate disappointment.

Answer (score 2):

I could get behind a feature request to not animate with rollover anything on the right hand side involving tags.

Heck, I could get behind disabling the movement altogether.